# Filter a listview with multiple spinners?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, listview

This code is a `listview` that shows the items in the `exercises[]` string. You can also search through these items with the `EditText` inputSearch and charsequence, and it detects what list item is selected by comparing strings.

**What I need is:**
A way to filter the listview (String exercises[]) by using multiple spinners?

**Full Code:**

```
public class CalExercises extends Activity {
    private ListView myListView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;
    EditText inputSearch;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calexercise);
        String exercises[] = {"Wall Pushup", "Knees Pushup", "Regular Pushup", "Pullup"};
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemSearch);
        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.parent_layout, R.id.parent_txt, exercises);
        myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                String PosItem = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                Intent itemIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TempCalEx.class);
                String exIntent = "";

                if ("Wall Pushup".equals(PosItem))
                    exIntent = "wallpushup";
                else if ("Knees Pushup".equals(PosItem))
                    exIntent = "kneepushup";
                else if ("Regular Pushup".equals(PosItem)) {
                    exIntent = "regpushup";
                    Toast.makeText(CalExercises.this, "List Detect Test Success - Pushup", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if ("Pullup".equals(PosItem)) {
                    exIntent = "pullup";
                    Toast.makeText(CalExercises.this, "List Detect Test Success - Pullup", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                itemIntent.putExtra("exString", exIntent);
                startActivity(itemIntent);


                ;
                inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        CalExercises.this.myAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                                  int arg3) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    }
                });


            }

            ;

        });

    }}
```

Comment: Just a note, You're using so many `if` to check for the string `PosItem` that's wrong because it compares the string 4 times even if it's the first occurrence so I think it's better to use `if, else if` or `if, else if, .... else` as whenever it finds the exact string it doesn't check the other conditions.

Comment: Yea I guess that woud make it more efficient. Thanks. Any idea on the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend using this code instead of copy pasting ;)

```
String PosItem = (String)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

Intent itemIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TempCalEx.class);
String exIntent = "";

if ("Wall Pushup".equals(PosItem))
    exIntent = "wallpushup";
else if ("Knees Pushup".equals(PosItem))
    exIntent = "kneepushup";
else if ("Regular Pushup".equals(PosItem)) {
    exIntent = "regpushup";
    Toast.makeText(CalExercises.this, "List Detect Test Success - Pushup",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else if ("Pullup".equals(PosItem)) {
    exIntent = "pullup";
    Toast.makeText(CalExercises.this, "List Detect Test Success - Pullup", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

itemIntent.putExtra("exString", exIntent);
startActivity(itemIntent);
```

I haven't tested this as i coded this in editor, but it should do exactly the same. It's easier to read, and due to the use of else if, should slightly improve performance.

Also if you are trying to compare Strings, always call equals on the Object you know, will never be null.

As to your original Question:

> A way to show which substrings will be displayed.

I don't get what it is you are trying to display. Do you want to Filter the List, or just react on certain clicks if the filter is set? Can you elaborate?

**EDIT**

This should work.

```
// setting up the map, you might have to add more.
Map <String, String[]> map = new Map<String, String[]>();

map.put("normal",new String[]{"Wall Pushup", "Knees Pushup", "Regular Pushup","Pullup"}); 
map.put("beginner",new String[]{"Knees Pushup","Wall Pushup"});

// this would be the spinner that selects the "normal", "beginner" etc
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        String[] content = map.get(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        if (content = null)
            myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.parent_layout, R.id.parent_txt, content));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    }

});
```

However you might have to Add more Arrays to the Map as i dont know all States that can occur.

And use the proper String as key, If your spinner shows "Beginner" you have to use put(key,value) with that exact text as key, or it will always be null. I would recommend using a custom adapter as your options with an arrayadapter are limited, but thats a different Story.

**Edit 2:**

```
public class CalExercises extends Activity {
private ListView myListView;
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;
EditText inputSearch;

List<String> exercises;

//TODO set those 2
Spinner spindif;
Spinner spinmus;

String[] array1;
String[] array2;

Map <String, String[]> map1 = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
Map <String, String[]> map2 = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calexercise);

    exercises = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Wall Pushup", "Knees Pushup", "Regular Pushup", "Pullup"}));

    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemSearch);
    spindif = (Spinner) findViewById((R.id.filterDif)); 
    spinmus = (Spinner) findViewById((R.id.filterMus)); 

    myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.parent_layout, R.id.parent_txt, exercises);
    myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            String PosItem = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

            Intent itemIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TempCalEx.class);
            String exIntent = "";

            if ("Wall Pushup".equals(PosItem))
                exIntent = "wallpushup";
            else if ("Knees Pushup".equals(PosItem))
                exIntent = "kneepushup";
            else if ("Regular Pushup".equals(PosItem)) {
                exIntent = "regpushup";
                Toast.makeText(CalExercises.this, "List Detect Test Success - Pushup", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if ("Pullup".equals(PosItem)) {
                exIntent = "pullup";
                Toast.makeText(CalExercises.this, "List Detect Test Success - Pullup", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            itemIntent.putExtra("exString", exIntent);
            startActivity(itemIntent);

            inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    CalExercises.this.myAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                              int arg3) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                }
            });


        }

        ;

    });

    // this would be the spinner that selects the "normal", "beginner" etc
    spindif.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            array1 = map1.get(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
            updateList();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        }

    });

    spinmus.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            array2 = map2.get(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
            updateList();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        }

    });
}

public void updateList() {
    List<Integer> aList =  Arrays.asList(array1);
    List<Integer> bList =  Arrays.asList(array2);
    aList.retainAll(bList);
    exercises = aList;
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

So this should do it.

Comment: Very informative response. Thanks! It already reacts to clicks even when filtered with search because I use the string equals instead of position. I guess you could say, I need it to filter the list, to the substrings I want shown. Example: The normal list atm is: Wall Pushup, Knees Pushup, Regular Pushup and Pullup. When the Spinner is set on 'Beginner', I only want to show Knees Pushup and Wall Pushup.

Comment: Okay I think I know what it is you are doing, so you dont want to search the List, you want to display groups of Items mapped to a keyword? I think I would create a Map<String,List<String>>, get the List for Each Keyword, i want to display, merge those lists, if it is possible to select more than one group. and set the resulting list into the adapter.

Comment: Thats the problem. Its from the exercises[] string. I want to show only a couple of them in the listview if the if-statements are met.

Comment: Exactly, that would be a way to do it. It seems however that, I am too inexperienced to pull that off! The start has already been made at (Public Void invokeFilter)

Comment: give a a few minutes, building the basic ;)

Comment: I have added Code that should show the stuff you need. You dont have to filter that list anymore, because it will contain only those Strings you want to show.

Comment: I am quite lost on what you are trying to do here. I have two spinners, wouldn't they clash? - Also, could you add it to my code as an proposed edit?

Comment: so, one spinner says "normal", "beginner" what does the other one do?

Comment: Give me a minute. Im gonna make it clear with pictures and all.

Comment: Well I dont actually think a picture would help. Let's say. Spinner 1 - Beginner/Intermediate/Expert  Spinner 2 - Chest/Back/Arms. If Spinner 1 is on Beginner and Spinner 2 is on Chest, it will show all the items that I classify as Beginner and Chest.  It should not interfere with any of the other features currently in the code, the itemclick intent, and the search function.

Comment: This is turning out way harder than expected.

Comment: You could create 2 maps, get Lists for each of the spinners, take those Strings that are in Both Lists and add them to the adapter as i did in my sample code. This should not interfere with your current features.

Comment: Could you add that to my code as an edit? I'm not sure where to put everything, also I cannot Instaniate a map, it should be clarified as a 'hashmap' or treemap etc.

Comment: You can just use a hashmap. The Problem is, that there are no references to the two spinners in your code, nor do i know what to dis play for each combination of the spinners.

Comment: Ill make the combinations, ill just need a example like a template, if thats okay.

Comment: You dont have to actually have the item/category names correct. :P

Comment: final Spinner spindif = (Spinner) findViewById((R.id.filterDif));
                final Spinner spinmus = (Spinner) findViewById((R.id.filterMus));
                final String diffilter = String.valueOf(spindif.getSelectedItem());
                final String musfilter = String.valueOf(spinmus.getSelectedItem());

Comment: I have added my code to yours, i hope you can figure out, how to continue.

Comment: List<Integer> gives an error? It says it should be <string>

Comment: Yes it should be String. Copy paste mistake.

Comment: Okay, tho the updatelist method crashes the activity.

Comment: without stacktrace, not possible to fix ;)

Comment: Did I still have to add anything that might prevent the crash? Im sure that all the references to the XML are correct now. Could you try and add 1 random string to the list by using a spinner? So I can see how that works.

Comment: Nothing i could think of. But as all of this is programmed theoretically because i can't actually test it, i didnt expect it to run, right away. But if you really want the app to run, you might want to think about looking into the crash yourself. Since you will be the one to fix/support the app

Comment: You are right tho I've been stuck on this for hours. I'm at that point were you start re-evaluating the point of life :P. I thought this would have been a easy thing to do. How different can the spinner be compared to the search function? It is basically the same thing. The search compares the entered characters, and filters the list by that. Can't I do the same thing with the filter?

Comment: Like if I add the 'category' to the name of every substring. so: "Wall Pushup - Beginner - Chest", "Knees Pushup - Intermediate - Chest"? Cant I just filter it on the char sequence like searching then??

Comment: that would work, but seems bad practice, id use an object instead of strings. add Categories to that string, and search for the object matching the selected categories, but then you would have to implement a custom adapter.

Comment: I'm  still learning so might aswell start it out easier, even though in the long run it would cost time, it would save me from a mental breakdown :). Well it all works how it should work now. Thank you for your help! The changes you made to my existing code cleaned up very nicely too! Have a good day